# Meaning of ncat connection nc:connect message?

Tags: netcat

I have a question regarding `ncat`. I have

```
nc: connect to <IP> port <PORT> (tcp) failed: Connection nc:connect
```

What does this mean?

Comment: It means nc failed to connect to the port specified on the host specified.  i.e. it may not be listening on that port.

Answer (score 1):

Netcat has been called "the Swiss army knife of TCP/IP"; it's a very flexible network client/server.

The error

> nc: connect to port (tcp) failed: Connection nc:connect

means that the TCP port number to which you tried to connect refused connection, for instance because there's no service running on that port, or a firewall is blocking connections on that port.